# Export Firefox Bookmarks to Mediawiki Wiki

Tags: firefox, import, export, mediawiki

Anybody know how I can convert my Firefox Bookmarks to a Mediawiki Wiki page?

I've tried exporting the Firefox Bookmarks to HTML and then entering that HTML into the wiki page that markup isn't recognized by Mediawiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try any of the tools listed on [MediaWiki's Editing Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Editing_tools#From_HTML) page.